# What is the difference between "./file" name and "../file name"

Tags: java, unix

actually I want to know What is the difference between `./file` name and `../file` name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a single dot indicates the current directory  a double dot is one level up or the parent directory.

Answer (score 11):

`.` refers to the current directory so `./file` would refer to the file/directory `file` in the current directory.

`..` refers the the parent directory so `../file` would refer to a file/directory called `file` in the parent directory (possibly the current directory if the current directory is called `file`.